# Omit rows with null values where other rows exist that have values

Tags: sql, group-by, null

Given this data:

```
| x  | y    |
| -- | ---- |
| a  | 1    |
| a  | null |
| b  | 2    |
| b  | 3    |
| b  | 3    |
| b  | null |
| b  | null |
| c  | null |
| c  | null |
```

I want to write a query that returns this result:

```
| x  | y    |
| -- | ---- |
| a  | 1    |
| b  | 2    |
| b  | 3    |
| c  | null |
```

That is to say, for a given x value, if there are rows with non-null y values, include all the distinct (x value, y value) rows and omit any (x value, null) rows. But, if for the x value, all the rows have null y, then return (x value, null).

Sample data

```
create table t (x text, y int);
insert into t
values ('a' , 1)
     , ('a' , null)
     , ('b' , 2)
     , ('b' , 3)
     , ('b' , 3)
     , ('b' , null)
     , ('b' , null)
     , ('c' , null)
     , ('c' , null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ways to do this. One way using `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
WITH 
  DistinctXYWithRowNumbers AS (
    SELECT
      *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY x ORDER BY y DESC) AS RowNumber
    FROM
      (SELECT DISTINCT x, y FROM t) DistinctXY
    )

SELECT
  x,
  y
FROM
  DistinctXYWithRowNumbers
WHERE
  NOT (y IS NULL AND RowNumber > 1)
ORDER BY
  x,
  y
;
```

Another way using a count table and `JOIN`:

```
WITH
  Counts AS (
    SELECT
      x, 
      COUNT(DISTINCT y) AS count
    FROM
      t
    GROUP BY
      x
    )

SELECT
  DistinctXY.*
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT x, y FROM t) DistinctXY
  LEFT JOIN Counts ON DistinctXY.x = Counts.x
WHERE
  NOT (y IS NULL AND count > 0)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use count window function as the following:

```
Select Distinct x, y 
From
 (
   Select x, y, 
    COUNT(Case When y Is Not null Then 1 End) Over (Partition By x) cn
   From t
 ) D
Where y Is Not null Or cn = 0
Order By x, y
```

Or you may use `Not Exists` with a correlated subquery as the following:

```
Select Distinct x, y From t As A
Where y Is Not null 
Or (y Is null And Not Exists(Select 1 From t As B Where B.x = A.x And B.y Is Not null))
Order By x, y
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/cYMNVCPa).